# SLES 10 Sp3 VMware tools error on install

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, sles, sles10

I installed SUSE enterprise server 10 SP3 on a Esx 4 server

The problem starts with the installation of vmware tools. "VmwareTools-4.0.0-193498.tar.gz"

The tools wont start: Unable to start services for vmware tools
Paravirtual ISCSI module: Failed
Guest vmxnet fast network device: Failed.

I fixed the guest vmxent ERROR by changing the NIC mode.

any hint? i cant be the only one with the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the Operating System Specific Packages supplied by vmware?

http://www.vmware.com/download/packages.html

I have much better luck installing the binary package via rug than building from the tar file.

Give it a shot an see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The OSPs from VMWare's repositories won't install either, they get halfway through and the transaction fails horribly, leaving you with several of the rpms install but two (the nox-mouse and nox-display-drv or something close to those) are installed halfway and can't be reinstalled/repaired or removed from your system cleanly.  It seems we really need VMWare to get off the ball and create some rpms that work on SLES 10 SP 3.

Note: the two that fail do so because of their scripts, you can force the removal of them if you've tried to load them via:  rpm -e --noscripts